# Change datatype at UserProfile table in Simple membership provider

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, simplemembership

i want to change datatype at UserId column in UserProfile table of simplemembership provider in my MVC 4 web application. because currently INT datatype is too small to store users so i want to change with LONG (bigint) datatype.

is it possible to do it ?

Comment: are you using entity framework ?

Comment: You're going to have more than 2.1 billion users? or are you setting the IDs manually? Either way, seems you may need something a little more robust than the SimpleMembershipProvider

Comment: Hi , thanks for response. Did u mean simple membership provider is not robust enough? I wanna know pros and con about it. A bit scare to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The schema for the SimpleMembershipProvider tables is fixed and you cannot change that. You will have to write a custom memberhsip provider.

But if you're gonna need to handle more than 2,147,483,647 (2.1 Billion users) in your system, the SimpleMembership provider is probably the last thing you're gonna have to consider as an option for this huge amount of data. So writing a custom membership provider is probably something you might need to consider anyway if you will be dealing with those kind of figures.

Comment: Hi, how about download source from Microsoft and change into to long all of the related methods and parameters?

Comment: Sure, that is a possibility. Just be careful if you are using third party packages that depend on the actual bits. Don't forget that the assemblies are strongly signed, which you won't be able to do with the same keys if you build from the source. So those third party packages won't work with your version.